# How do you put any array type in a function parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I want to make a function that randomizes the order of an array.
I used this function

```
    public func randomizeIntArrayOrder(_ array: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var newArray = [0]
    var unUsedNumbers = [0]
    unUsedNumbers.removeAll()
    newArray.removeAll()
    for i in 0 ... array.count - 1 {
        unUsedNumbers.append(i)
    }
    for _ in 0 ... array.count - 1 {
        newArray.append(array[unUsedNumbers.remove(at: randomInt(from: 0, to: unUsedNumbers.count - 1))])
    }
    return newArray
    }
```

But it only works for Int arrays. Is there a way to make a function parameter accept any type of array and return any type of array?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Just `let randomizedArray = sortedArray.shuffled()`

Comment: "But it only works for Int arrays. Is there a way to make a function parameter accept any type of array and return any type of array?" Look into "Generics" in the Swift language guide. I  strongly suggested reading the whole thing https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: Also, never write `0 ... array.count - 1`. It's bound to blow up. See https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Proper%20Array%20Iteration.md